# I cant apply the combinatorics concept to this problem

Tags: combinatorics

```
In a ‘Goal of the season’ competition, participants are asked to 
rank ten goals in order of quality. The organisers select their 
‘correct’ order at random. Anybody who matches their order will be 
invited to join the television commentary team for the next international match. 

(i) What is the probability of a participant’s order being the same as 
that of the organisers? 

(ii)  Five million people enter the competition. How many people 
would be expected to join the commentary team?
```

For (i): my answer is 1/10!

For (ii): I dont know how to get the number of people who can guess the answer correctly.
The only guess i have is (1/10!)*5000 000.
But this does not seem right. How do I solve this?

Comment: Probability variation/average value?

Comment: You got it.  Each person is correct with probability $p=\frac 1{10!}$ so, by linearity of expectation, the expected number of successes in $N$ trials is $p\times N$.  Note:  it doesn't even matter if the people choose dependently or independently, so long as they each have probability $p$ of success.

Comment: @lulu thank you.